# Derivation of Einstein's equation

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, field-theory, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm reading Weinberg's book on General relativity and I don't quite follow his arguments on the derivation of Einstein's equation. In the following, index $ab$ is 4-dim, while $ij$ is 3-dim.

Okay, so he find Einstein's equation must be of the form:$$CG_{ab}=C(R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R)=-8\pi GT_{ab}$$
with $C$ be a real constant number undetermined, and to decide the equation, we just need to determine $C$.  To do so, Weinberg argued that the equation must degenerate to the Newtonian equation, which is $$\nabla^2g_{00}=-8\pi GT_{00}$$
He then said that when we are in the situation where Newton's theory holds, we must have $$\big|T_{ij}\big|\ll\big|T_{00}\big|$$ and therefore $$\big|G_{ij}\big|\ll\big|G_{00}\big|$$ I understand this, but I don't think I understand what he then argued, he said due to the above facts, we must have in Newton's limit:$$R_{ij}\simeq\frac{1}{2}g_{ij}R$$
Why this is true? There seems no logics to me to claim so. We can only conclude $$\frac{\big|G_{ij}\big|}{\big|G_{00}\big|}\simeq 0$$but this does not need to imply $$G_{ij}\simeq 0$$ which is his conclusion said. Any suggests?

Comment: Note that it's $R_{00}$ in the third-last equation, not $R$.

Comment: My apologize, I typed it wrong. It should be $R$ instead of $R_{00}$

Comment: @GK1202 I was looking at equation 10 here.  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannTensor.html And I noticed that if you equate the coefficients of the metric terms then you get your identity. I don't know if that's a coincidence. But I feel it probably isn't/